# Can send an automatic print request from a website hosted on a web server to a printer located on a local network?

Tags: c#, asp.net, printing

Consider an online shop web site(asp.net web site) hosted on a shared web server. customers buy multiple items and pay for them. the detail information of that order will store in website DB. i want after inserting the record in database, automatically that order being printed with the printer located on my local network in my office, is it feasible?

Comment: you should show what have you tried.